# changing bootstrap class in modal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change bootstrap modal content (bootstrap classes) with jQuery. I want to replace *col-xs-8* with *col-xs-12*. Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<div id="regModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog firstReg rtl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="login-modal">
                <div class="modal-header"></div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        </div>
                        <div id = "#main-form" class="col-xs-8">
                            <p> 111111111</p>
                            <p class = "hidden"> 222222222</p>
                        </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <p><a>click </a></p>

                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**modal.js:**

```
$("#regModal a").click(function() {
    $("#regModal .col-xs-4").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#main-form").removeClass('col-xs-8').addClass('col-xs-12');

});
```

I also used

```
$("#regModal #main-form").attr('col-xs-8' , 'col-xs-12')
```

But either first method or second is not working and cannot expand col-xs-8 to col-xs-12. Any suggestion?

**EDITED:** Also , I want to show second *p*  after changing col-xs-8 to col-xs-12.Here is my css code:

```
#regModal .hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: There's no `a` element in `#regModal`, which is why the `click` event will not be firing.

Comment: @Yass I've changed my question

Comment: Please see my answer below. Let me know if there are any issues with the solution I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#regModal a").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $col4 = $("#regModal .col-xs-4").fadeOut(2000);
  $col4.next().removeClass('col-xs-8').addClass('col-xs-12');

  var $firstChild = $col4.next().children().first().hide();
  $firstChild.next().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

I'm first obtaining the 4 column content and storing it in a variable (`$col4`) and at the same time invoking the `fadeOut` method. Since I have a reference to the 4 column content and the 8 column content is the next sibling, I can use the `next` method to find the element and execute the required actions.

I'm using the same principle for hiding/showing the child `p` elements of the 12 column element.

You can set some css rules for `.col-xs-12` to provide a visual indication of the change when the class is applied (if you want to).

```
.col-xs-12 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/9p88j3jk/)**

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I edited my question again. can you help me to complete this? I want to show hidden paragraph after changing col-md-8 to col-md-12.